# Pintar números respecto a checkbox

Tags: php, html5, formularios

¿Como puedo hacer para que mediante unos `checkbox` los cuales son "todos" "**múltiplos** de 2" "múltiplos de 3" y  "múltiplos de 5", el `php` haga un solo recorrido con `for` y me muestre los múltiplos de los números seleccionados en el `checkbox`?

Importante saber que el rango de números con el que va a trabajar el bucle `for` los introduce el usuario, yo he llegado hasta aqui:

**FORMULARIO HTML**

```
Numeros a los que enviar el mensaje: <br><br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="Nums" value="Todos" />Todos<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Nums" value="Mult2"/>Multiplos de 2<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Nums" value="Mult3"/>Multiplos de 3<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Nums" value="Mult5"/>Multiplos de 5<br><br>
```

**CODIGO PHP**

```
function Mostrar_Numeros ($zapatofonoinicio, $zapatofonolast,$nums){

 if($nums=="Mult2") {
  $limite=$zapatofonolast;
  $numero=2;

 for($i=$zapatofonoinicio;$i<=$zapatofonolast;$i++){
 if($i%$numero==0){
 echo ("$i <br>");
  }
 }
} 

if($nums=="Mult3")
{
 $limite=$zapatofonolast;
 $numero=3;

for($i=$zapatofonoinicio;$i<=$zapatofonolast;$i++){
if($i%$numero==0){
echo ("$i <br>");
   }
  }
}

if($nums=="Mult5")
{
 $limite=$zapatofonolast;
 $numero=5;

for($i=$zapatofonoinicio;$i<=$zapatofonolast;$i++){
  if($i%$numero==0){
  echo ("$i <br>");
  }
 }
}   

if($nums=="Todos"){
$limite=$zapatofonolast;
for($i=$zapatofonoinicio;$i<=$zapatofonolast;$i++){
{
echo ("$i <br>");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: No entiendo que es lo que selecciona el usuario, puedes explicar eso?

Comment: @LuisFernando Muy Buenas, te comento: 
El usuario, introduce el rango de números, es decir: $zapatofonoinicio y $zapatofonolast, y de ese rango de números que el ha introducido, después elije los que quiere visualizar con los checkbox antes mencionados, espero haberlo aclarado y gracias por tu comentario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDITADA***

No habia entendido bien tu pregunta, lo que necesitas entonces se puede hacer de esta manera.

Primero tus checkbox deberian tener como name un array de esta manera, porque sino nunca vas a poder pasar mas de un valor en un mismo nombre:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Nums[]" value="Todos" />Todos<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Nums[]" value="Mult2"/>Multiplos de 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Nums[]" value="Mult3"/>Multiplos de 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Nums[]" value="Mult5"/>Multiplos de 5<br><br>
```

Por lo tanto en `$_POST["Nums"]` (o GET) te llega un array con los valores seleccionados

Por otro lado la funcion puede ser de la siguiente manera:

```
function Mostrar_Numeros ($inicio, $fin, $multiplos){

    $resultados = array();
    foreach($multiplos as $multiplo){
        $divisor="";
        switch($multiplo){
            case "Mult2":
                $divisor = 2;
            break;
            case "Mult3":
                $divisor = 3;
            break;
            case "Mult5":
                $divisor = 5;
            break;
            case "Todos":
                $divisor = 1;
            break;
        }


        $ini = $inicio;
        for($ini; $ini<=$fin; $ini++){
            if($ini % $divisor == 0){
                if(!in_array($ini, $resultados))   
                    array_push($resultados, $ini);
            }
        }
    }

    asort($resultados);
    foreach($resultados as $resultado)
    {
      echo $resultado."|";
    }
}
```

Y lo testearias de esta manera, por ejemplo suponiendo que en `$_POST["Nums"]` (o GET) te llega en el array "Mult2" y "Mult3":

```
$multiplos = array("Mult2", "Mult3");//Emula llegada por $_POST["Nums"] o $_GET["Nums"]
Mostrar_Numeros(1,15,$multiplos);
```

Te dejo un sandbox actualizado [aca](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b46add91ac06f3f6bc6a4f050027324f2e2357ad)

Ahora vos hablas de realizar esto con un solo for, no veo la manera de hacerlo ya que no sabes cuantos checkbox va a seleccionar el usuario.

Comment: Hasta ahi habia llegado yo, el caso es que se puedan ejecutar varios multiplos a la vez, por ejemplo si selecciono los multiplos de 2 y los multiplos de 3 que me muestre solo multiplos de 2 y de 3 sin repetir valores como por ejemplo el 6, Gracias por tu interes y tu respuesta, un saludo

Comment: Una cuestion más, mira, cuando lo testéo me sale lo siguiente elija lo que elija: "Array ( [0] => 1 )" Como puedo arreglar esto?, y de verdad muchisimas gracias por tomarte tantas molestias.

Comment: Lo probaste en el sandbox que te pase y te sale eso?

Comment: En el sandbox que me pasaste salia genial, pero despues lo pasé a mi ejercicio y me salia lo que te pasé, pero ya lo solucioné

Comment: Grande @LeonardoCabré , Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: me alegro que te haya servido, saludos